# Respect Validation: What's the right validation rule when a form has several fields with the same name?

Tags: php, validation, respect-validation

I have a form that has only fields:

- question
- choice

Choice is an array because a question has more than answers and the user can add as many as I need.

I just need to validate that these aren't empty so I tried:

```
$validation = $this->c->validator->validate($request, [
            'question' => v::notEmpty(),
            'choice[]' => v::ArrayVal()->each()->notEmpty()
        ]);
```

But it doesn't let me save any entry. If I leave choice[] as "choice" it validates every entry. I assume the rule must be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [KeySet](http://respect.github.io/Validation/docs/keyset.html) validator:

```
$response = v::keySet(
    v::key('question', v::notEmpty()),
    v::key('choice', v::arrayVal())
)->validate($request);
```

In the case you use the given value:

```
$request = [
    'question' => 'What is your first name?',
    'choice' => []
];
```

the validation returns `true`.

In the case you use the given value:

```
$request = [
    'question' => 'What is your first name?',
    'choice' => ''
];
```

the validation returns `false`.